# Shadow effect (elevation) is hiding after app was launched

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design

I have a problem with elevation effect in my app (shadow under TabLayout exactly) that is collapsing after I'm running my App. It's visible in preview mode but not on my device cause it's hiding. This is my code:

Main Activity

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:clipToPadding="false">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_material_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background_portrait"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />`

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    /></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is code of styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/editTextIndigo</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/editTextPink</item>
</style>

<style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
<style name="MineCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

styles-v21.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
```

And here is my screen while running app:

[via GIPHY](http://giphy.com/gifs/l3vRbvE9IMDSj9qzS)

I want to achieve simple shadow effectt that is not hiding under tablayout to seperate from the rest of the content. I'm testing it on my phone with android 6.0.1

Comment: try app:elevation="20dp".

Comment: no effect in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem. I have created Relative layout with view inside that imitates shadow. Adding this line of code after TabLayout and before end of AppBarLayout solved everything.

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/tabs"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/white">


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/tablayout_shadow"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And here is full code of main_activity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:clipToPadding="false">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_material_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background_portrait"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />



    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/tabs"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/white">


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
```

tablayout_shadow.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:endColor="#88333333"
    android:angle="90"/>
```

Finally after 2 days of brainstorming i solved it:D. I hope this will help someone in future.